# fetchMore() and refetch() doesn't resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo, angular16

I am trying to add pagination to a list of messages rendered on the page. I call my graphql backend-endpoint fetching the first 10 messages with watch. Works fine. Then on clicking button Load More function loadMore() is called to fetchMore() messages.
The request is send to the server and the response is successfully send to the frontend if I look in the networks tab showing the correct messages. But it looks like apollo doesnt recognize the response. Neither the promise is resolved (code in .then() is not called) nor the cache is updated or the merge function is called. The request isnt even listed in the apollo client devtools.

My graphql.module.ts:

```
import {APOLLO_OPTIONS, ApolloModule} from 'apollo-angular';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-angular/http';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache, ApolloClient, ApolloLink} from '@apollo/client/core';
import {setContext} from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import {AuthService} from "@auth0/auth0-angular";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import {firstValueFrom, lastValueFrom} from "rxjs";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {ErrorLink, onError} from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {offsetLimitPagination, relayStylePagination} from "@apollo/client/utilities";
import {ReadFieldFunction} from '@apollo/client/cache/core/types/common';
import {CompetitionMessage} from "./models/competition.model";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";

const uri = environment.api.serverUrl; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  const http = httpLink.create({
    uri: uri + '/graphql',
  });

  return {
    connectToDevTools: !environment.production,
    link: http,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(
      {
        addTypename: true,
        typePolicies: {
          Query: {
            fields: {
              getMessages: offsetLimitPagination(),
              // getMessages: {
              //   keyArgs: false,
              //   merge(existing, incoming) {
              //     return [...(existing ?? []), ...(incoming ?? [])]
              //   },
              // }
            }
          },
        }
      }
    ),
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        errorPolicy: 'all',
      },
    },
  }
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ApolloModule, BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {
}
```

competition-details.component.ts:

```
import {Component, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CompetitionMessagesQuery} from "../../services/gql/competition-gq.service";
import {CompetitionMessage, CompetitionMessageConnection, CompetitionMessageEdge} from "../../models/competition.model";
import {MessageFormatterService} from "../../services/message-formatter.service";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-competition-details',
  templateUrl: './competition-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./competition-details.component.scss']
})
export class CompetitionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoading: boolean;
  cursor: number;
  messages$: Observable<CompetitionMessage[]>;
  private messagesQueryRef: any;

  constructor(
    private competitionMessagesQuery: CompetitionMessagesQuery,
    private messageFormatterService: MessageFormatterService,
  ) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messagesQueryRef = this.competitionMessagesQuery.watch({offset: null, limit: 10},
      {
        errorPolicy: "all",
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      }
    );
    this.messages$ = this.messagesQueryRef.valueChanges.pipe(
      map((result: any) => {
        this.cursor = result.data.getMessages.length;
        return result.data.getMessages
          ;
      })
    );
  }

  loadMore() {
    if (this.isLoading) {
      return;
    }

    this.messagesQueryRef.fetchMore({
      variables: {offset: this.cursor, limit: 10}
    }).then((r: any) => { // Check the result here
      console.log("Data:", r);
    });
  }

  formatMessage(message?: string): string {
    if (!message) return "";
    return this.messageFormatterService.formatMessage(message);
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll($event: any) {
    let threshold = 150; // You can change this threshold per your requirement.
    let position = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
    let height = document.body.scrollHeight;

    if (position > height - threshold) {
      this.loadMore();
    }
  }
}
```

competition-details.component.html:

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let message of (messages$ | async)">{{ message.id + ' ' + formatMessage(message.message) }}</li>
  </ul>
  <button (click)="loadMore()">Load more</button>
```

and my graphql query:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CompetitionMessagesQuery extends Query<{ getMessages: CompetitionMessage[] }> {
  override document = gql`
    query getMessages($limit: Int, $offset: Int) {
      getMessages(limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
        id
        message
        messageType
        referenceObjectId
        referenceObjectType
        createdDateTime
        changedDateTime
      }
    }
  `;
}
```

response from watch():

```
{
    "data": {
        "getMessages": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "message": "v4kh7dFitpPVgDtDA9F6P97ltce5fLqe1SNwp31U85s6AF9E5uFeanMs8WDaykSj",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "message": "82NCn5OGFxC4gWD1EvELIDRqI5VOFG1SpFXdY3CLvWV6KpRatt1hfaGl5VvX2ytr",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "message": "fCTuM9e8yg7CB1HAZCEbgRVnebHcfBrD2ZGUIHP0x1uwivMnC0kEmuUvIliln3j2",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "message": "LwoMBTVRsOMUl2tTqOkxexIpCSkVjuYJf8reu4mQEylQqCRhwP29roBwPt27l3Qt",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "message": "KPcP7o8isL9WBAkmFtjyEZN5d4MVqdn19D4oal7WwRbc4fJA8nVk4iDkgK0YtCFo",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "message": "WF19VwDw6i6qcm8caj1By93aGjh60oJYRRnlBCLW7cPW7augYJP73jlwOtKa7Q2V",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "message": "hlYOTgatARZgnjDE73jNiqLI7MSdgEq3CyngtAUKLb7anYlmKNYXawMXo63Dbx1o",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "message": "lcX7gBWRlMx8jcw9gXsfPu9t1PQJvcsetXsyXvIQtKZYjdLTsqnp0gScLVXXh67w",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "message": "eiBvvflMZpo7LV94xcjtKuErIDZC6m79qt8NxbNenDgNpZpP4ih67rR1fZeSqUwg",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "10",
                "message": "vjlYJAp4ENxdxYK5JFS7HVXeHpgrl66iuu7UiE239fa4gHLPsWTTNYg0ckRv7Cw3",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and response from fetchMore(), which apollo seems to ignore somehow:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getMessages": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "message": "elAgScJcbnuwYdNeet4kPOwUDebmNaxDL7pMBAaJ8KK96B0bPtZTp1p2erVULMlV",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "message": "d9rlVUK56vUg0EWWrY9QvkCr5jup1WJD6viFU46uqBjOC8bRsfRmp9BZH1ydWKyM",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "message": "PHpbHAMLNrEXNipAN655cjdNsG68y6XUSkqwsDYwr9qS1yuZ8T5fkUvHe13J8FmT",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "message": "O977WujT5GOl2FywnwHpqaG71uJ7TM1UkX821boxZ6OlK4RF21OitYN9aPjM4bK9",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "15",
                "message": "d8ZBRkaJZTQfPIsta9U9h0PSfkqfZgwItkNEnk7TsEoYHPbfwhLcmV9WTXtpI9N6",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "16",
                "message": "KO9cGmu6Y1nQ5jDDVjQShFtikqlgjDUn3OjV3qZmc4IvdHvWHiVdfPuOiArjF1QZ",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "17",
                "message": "iaUQr2vt3hU58KB6PGabvoEP0ExPgBQ6736kUUFcN2aNYe9Ihh40O17Rentxg4r2",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "18",
                "message": "iAHYc9xgVJSp5c0bb8sDE5kcoCKM8WUReNBISRMOVGpyyi73H3dEBlSC7xvbrurk",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "19",
                "message": "0Mp5pb7Y4WSPGyIs7UjuxGl0v8bGSt3gmERD4ckcOovDLGjSms5X2eEKZw4lG9tb",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            },
            {
                "id": "20",
                "message": "aYaAXR049DNHkuqInd8QBIkw5OECW7DssLayiqELhhMWhE5CDgpXCc9M7GPUmyRW",
                "messageType": "TRADE_OPEN",
                "referenceObjectId": "1",
                "referenceObjectType": "JOURNAL",
                "createdDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "changedDateTime": "2024-01-19T09:04:51.288Z",
                "__typename": "CompetitionMessage"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have no clue why the Promise of fetchMore() doesn't resolve or what else to try to find the problem. The same happens if I use refetch(). The http request is send and response recieved but the promise doesnt resolve.

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.8.10"
"apollo-angular": "^5.0.2"
"@angular/cli": "~16.2.10"
```